# conjure-up stuck Attempting to connect to the bootstrapped node

Tags: juju, maas

conjure-up --bootstrap-to  command was issued.
It did bootstrap and maas did install ubuntu and the host is up and running. However, the conjure-up is hung at:

```
user@maas:~/.cache/conjure-up/landscape$ cat conjure-up-cloud-maas-935-b96-bootstrap.err
Creating Juju controller "conjure-up-cloud-maas-935-b96" on cloud-maas-935
Looking for packaged Juju agent version 2.2.1 for amd64
Launching controller instance(s) on cloud-maas-935...
 - kkc8hw (arch=amd64 mem=16G cores=8)
Fetching Juju GUI 2.7.5
Waiting for address
Attempting to connect to 10.0.0.102:22
user@maas:~/.cache/conjure-up/landscape$
```

When I looked at the conjure-up log, this is what its stuck at:

```
 2017-07-25 09:28:49,568 [DEBUG] conjure-up/_unspecified_spell - app.py:258 - LXD version: 2.14, Juju version: 2.2.1-xenial-amd64, conjure-up version: 2.2.2
2017-07-25 09:28:49,637 [INFO] conjure-up/_unspecified_spell - events.py:178 - Watching for shutdown
2017-07-25 09:28:49,749 [DEBUG] conjure-up/_unspecified_spell - events.py:55 - Awaiting Shutdown at conjureup/events.py:180
2017-07-25 09:28:56,564 [DEBUG] conjure-up/landscape - download.py:60 - Path is local filesystem, copying /snap/conjure-up/549/spells/landscape to /home/user/.cache/conjure-up/landscape
2017-07-25 09:28:56,571 [DEBUG] conjure-up/landscape - utils.py:392 - Pulling bundle for landscape-dense-maas from channel: stable
2017-07-25 09:29:59,047 [DEBUG] conjure-up/landscape - juju.py:432 - {'clouds': {'cloud-maas-935': {'type': 'maas', 'auth-types': ['oauth1'], 'endpoint': 'http://10.0.0.1:5240/MAAS'}}}
2017-07-25 09:30:00,394 [INFO] conjure-up/landscape - common.py:77 - Bootstrapping Juju controller.
2017-07-25 09:30:00,395 [DEBUG] conjure-up/landscape - juju.py:170 - bootstrap cmd: ['juju', 'bootstrap', 'cloud-maas-935', 'conjure-up-cloud-maas-935-b96', '--default-model', 'conjure-landscape-f6b', '--config', 'image-stream=daily', '--config', 'enable-os-upgrade=false', '--to', 'real-kite', '--bootstrap-series', 'xenial', '--credential', 'conjure-cloud-maas-935-4b9']
2017-07-25 09:30:00,430 [DEBUG] conjure-up/landscape - events.py:55 - Awaiting ModelConnected at conjureup/controllers/deploy/common.py:23
2017-07-25 09:30:00,474 [DEBUG] conjure-up/landscape - juju.py:179 - waiting for proc
2017-07-25 09:30:00,969 [DEBUG] conjure-up/landscape - maas.py:401 - Found endpoint: http://10.0.0.1:5240/MAAS for cloud: cloud-maas-935
2017-07-25 09:30:00,974 [DEBUG] conjure-up/landscape - events.py:55 - Setting MAASConnected at conjureup/controllers/deploy/gui.py:285
2017-07-25 09:30:02,004 [DEBUG] conjure-up/landscape - gui.py:13 - Rendering bootstrap wait
2017-07-25 09:30:02,212 [DEBUG] conjure-up/landscape - events.py:55 - Awaiting MAASConnected at conjureup/controllers/deploy/gui.py:209 in task _do_deploy at conjureup/controllers/deploy/gui.py:239
2017-07-25 09:30:02,214 [DEBUG] conjure-up/landscape - events.py:55 - Received MAASConnected at conjureup/controllers/deploy/gui.py:209 in task _do_deploy at conjureup/controllers/deploy/gui.py:239
2017-07-25 09:30:02,216 [DEBUG] conjure-up/landscape - events.py:55 - Awaiting PreDeployComplete at conjureup/juju.py:517 in task _do_deploy at conjureup/controllers/deploy/gui.py:239
2017-07-25 09:30:02,426 [DEBUG] conjure-up/landscape - events.py:55 - Awaiting MAASConnected at conjureup/controllers/deploy/gui.py:209 in task _do_deploy at conjureup/controllers/deploy/gui.py:239
2017-07-25 09:30:02,428 [DEBUG] conjure-up/landscape - events.py:55 - Received MAASConnected at conjureup/controllers/deploy/gui.py:209 in task _do_deploy at conjureup/controllers/deploy/gui.py:239
2017-07-25 09:30:02,429 [DEBUG] conjure-up/landscape - events.py:55 - Awaiting PreDeployComplete at conjureup/juju.py:517 in task _do_deploy at conjureup/controllers/deploy/gui.py:239
2017-07-25 09:30:02,584 [DEBUG] conjure-up/landscape - events.py:55 - Awaiting MAASConnected at conjureup/controllers/deploy/gui.py:209 in task _do_deploy at conjureup/controllers/deploy/gui.py:239
2017-07-25 09:30:02,585 [DEBUG] conjure-up/landscape - events.py:55 - Received MAASConnected at conjureup/controllers/deploy/gui.py:209 in task _do_deploy at conjureup/controllers/deploy/gui.py:239
2017-07-25 09:30:02,587 [DEBUG] conjure-up/landscape - events.py:55 - Awaiting PreDeployComplete at conjureup/juju.py:517 in task _do_deploy at conjureup/controllers/deploy/gui.py:239
2017-07-25 09:30:02,778 [DEBUG] conjure-up/landscape - events.py:55 - Awaiting MAASConnected at conjureup/controllers/deploy/gui.py:209 in task _do_deploy at conjureup/controllers/deploy/gui.py:239
2017-07-25 09:30:02,780 [DEBUG] conjure-up/landscape - events.py:55 - Received MAASConnected at conjureup/controllers/deploy/gui.py:209 in task _do_deploy at conjureup/controllers/deploy/gui.py:239
2017-07-25 09:30:02,781 [DEBUG] conjure-up/landscape - events.py:55 - Awaiting PreDeployComplete at conjureup/juju.py:517 in task _do_deploy at conjureup/controllers/deploy/gui.py:239
2017-07-25 09:30:02,800 [DEBUG] conjure-up/landscape - events.py:55 - Awaiting Bootstrapped at conjureup/controllers/bootstrapwait/gui.py:37
2017-07-25 09:30:02,818 [DEBUG] conjure-up/landscape - events.py:55 - Awaiting RelationsAdded:haproxy at /snap/conjure-up/549/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/events.py:127 in task wait at conjureup/events.py:95
2017-07-25 09:30:02,822 [DEBUG] conjure-up/landscape - events.py:55 - Awaiting RelationsAdded:rabbitmq-server at /snap/conjure-up/549/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/events.py:127 in task wait at conjureup/events.py:95
2017-07-25 09:30:02,825 [DEBUG] conjure-up/landscape - events.py:55 - Awaiting RelationsAdded:postgresql at /snap/conjure-up/549/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/events.py:127 in task wait at conjureup/events.py:95
2017-07-25 09:30:02,828 [DEBUG] conjure-up/landscape - events.py:55 - Awaiting RelationsAdded:landscape-server at /snap/conjure-up/549/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/events.py:127 in task wait at conjureup/events.py:95
```

I have tried this step multiple times and somehow unable to get through this stage.
Anybody knows what could be wrong here?

```
user@maas:~/.cache/conjure-up/landscape$ snap list
Name        Version    Rev   Developer  Notes
conjure-up  2.2.2      549   canonical  classic
core        16-2.26.9  2381  canonical  -
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured out why it was stuck there.
I think I am right here:
Basically, in the MAAS server the internal subnet the gateway was 10.0.0.254 instead of 10.0.0.1. Changed the gateway and that in turn was able to help in dns forwarding.